# stream udp-> rtsp server

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp, rtsp-server

Try to launch the rtsp server with udp stram from /dev/video
cam(/dev/video0 -> udp -> rtsp) server
but I can not hear from the server
but the thing is it just not automcaically spit the error message 
it take time (around 15 seconds and spit the error message)

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=1024 speed-preset=ultrafast ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=0.0.0.0 port=8554
    Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
    Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
    Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
    Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
    New clock: GstSystemClock
    Redistribute latency...
    Redistribute latency...
    0:03:46.5 / 99:99:99.
```

it successfully stream the webcam -> udp stream

then I try to redirect to the rtsp server

https://github.com/steabert/gst-rtsp-launch

change Dockerfile

```
CMD ["udpsrc port=8554 ! application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96"]
```

Then try to receive the directed stream

```
 gst-launch-1.0 -vvv rtspsrc location=rtsp://0.0.0.0:8554/test ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink sync=false
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Prerolled, waiting for progress to finish...
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://0.0.0.0:8554/test
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0: Unhandled error
Additional debug info:
../gst/rtsp/gstrtspsrc.c(6795): gst_rtspsrc_send (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0:
Service Unavailable (503)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```